# Raspberry pi: No internet access

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get internet connection at my university. I have enabled sharing on my wifi settings and connected to the raspberry pi VIA ethernet connection.

The IP used for ethernet connection is:  192.168.137.1 however, i do not have a default gateway address (Tried restarting computer, still didn't work as well as `ipconfig /release` and `/renew`).

My raspberry pi: 192.168.13

When SSH'ing into my pi i ran 
`sudo route add default gw 192.168.137.1`

To test my internet connection, however it doesn't work and infact makes `ping google.com` slower to run than usual.

I have nothing in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/interfaces` at the moment, i'm simply trying to test the internet connection then use the details and place it in `/interfaces`.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, i also tried installing DHCP server as well as disabling firewall and still doesn't work

Note: I managed to get internet connection at my university but it was extremely slow and unreliable.

EDIT: I am using Windows 8.1 OS if this helps, i have heard there are issues depending on OS

Comment: Are you sure you ran `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`?  That shouldn't work on Raspbian / Linux.  Try `sudo dhclient [interface]` to obtain a DHCP configuration.

Comment: I will try, however i'm facing an issue with the ethernet port on the raspberry pi at the moment, i closed PuTTY and now when i want to re-connect the raspberry pi up it's not showing the OK lights.

Comment: In that case also double check the port upstream that you're connecting to as well.

Comment: Afraid it doesn't work, i run `sudo dhclient eth0` however it doesn't return back to `pi@raspberrypi` i can just keep typing after i run that command

Comment: And my port upstream is good, after noticing that i accidentally deleted the kernel...

Comment: You may be able to type afterward, but it won't be effective. You must reconnect with ssh. The prompt lets you know that you are reconnected. Disconnecting is expected when releasing and renewing the IP address.